# Как напечатать 2 страницы на одном листе C# ( с одной стороны листа, две маленькие страницы)

Tags: c#, принтер

Как программно объяснить принтеру, что нужно печатать 2 страницы на одном листе, а не две обычных страницы по целому листу? А то каждый раз лазить в настройки принтера не комильфо

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду двухстороннюю печать или отображение 2х страниц на 1? С каким инструментом вы работаете? Добавьте больше информации пожалуйста

Comment: Отображение 2х страниц на одном листе ( в настройках принтера называется 2 страницы на листе) 
Печатаю из webbrowser заранее сгенерированную web страницу.
webBrowser1.ShowPrintDialog();